# Does Linkedin API support CORS preflight OPTIONS request?

Tags: ajax, cors, laravel-5.5, linkedin-api, laravel-socialite

i'm building "one single page" app with laravel v5.5.32 and i'm using Socialite with jquery Ajax to retrieve user's data from Linkedin to prefill subscription form but i'm running into CORS preflight OPTIONS request.

i installed [Barryvdh laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) to handle CORS request but it seems not working and i'm still getting error.

i already opened an [issue](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors/issues/281)

i appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to load linkedin access token generator page in you html page,Linkedin server itself is not accepting CORS, better to load that url in openwindow popup,
i to have faced this issue before.